# How do I animate a following filter layout in android on scroll of recyclerView

Tags: android, animation

[image]

[image]

I want to animate the first image like when I scroll the recyclerview up then it should expand equal to width of the mobile device display and when I scroll down it should collapse. It's kind of expand and collapse the below black background layout when I scroll the recylcerview. How do I do this, any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener()`

Comment: Yes, @Chisko I am RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener() only, Inside that I want to expand the above black background filter layout when I scroll down and collapse it as it is to its original state when I scroll up.

Comment: There are already plenty of answered questions that teach you how to do this, only not specifically as yours. I think you need to try harder.

Comment: yea @Chisko I will